# WebKit height differences

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, webkit

**Picture**

[image: columns]

**CSS**

```css
#sub-nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 207px;
    left: 16px;
    width: 192px;
    z-index: 4;
    background: url('../img/transparent.png');
    overflow: hidden;
}

#logo-buttons-bg {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 0 60px 0;
    width: 208px;   
    //background-gradient 
    z-index: 8;
}

#logo-buttons-bg ul {
    padding: 8px 21px;
    list-style-type: none;  
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
var containerHeight = $("#logo-buttons-bg ul").height();
$("#sub-nav").height(containerHeight - 25);
```

How can I fix it ? I've tried to add different elements for `var containerHeight`, changed `25` to another CSS element with specific height… the result is exactly the same.

---

Normalize.css fixed the problem, Thanks to **Vucko**

Comment: Are you using some [css reset](http://www.cssreset.com/)?

Comment: and how looks that html code?

Comment: please provide a jsfiddle.

Comment: @Are you using some css reset?

No, i'll try to add one, thx

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with FF and Chrome. I was using .height and switched to .outerHeight(true)

http://princepthomas.blogspot.com/2011/07/jquery-height-vs-outerheight.html